# Reactive Dexie-Query in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, dexie

I am using Dexie and would like to implement this in my Vue 3 frontend.

In the mount() method, I query the database using the following example and assign this to a local variable in the Vue template which is then rendered.

```
const oldFriends = await db.friends
        .where('age').above(75)
        .toArray(); 

this.friends = oldFriends;
```

Now I have a situation where a web worker changes the IndexedDB, and writes new values in there via Dexie (so in this example, adds another friend).

Now how do I make my Vue component notice this update and render the "new" friend - so the Dexie query becomes reactive?

Comment: I found useLiveQuery() for react - this is exactly what I need in Vue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDIT: [Here's a sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-tereshkova-b6dfi?file=/src/components/DBItems.vue) I tried to create out of my limited vue knowledge*

You need to npm install dexie@next and import { liveQuery } from "dexie".

This new feature was introduced a year ago and allow you to turn an async function into an observable as long as it only queries your database.

It's described in these release notes: https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/releases/tag/v3.1.0-alpha.1

And on the following blog: https://medium.com/dexie-js/awesome-react-integration-coming-f212c2273d05

So, there's both 'liveQuery' and 'useLiveQuery'. The former is the framework agnostic one, included in dexie library itself and the latter just a some react sugar on top of it.

Comment: Hey David. It's great to get a response from you personally. Thanks also for your great work in the project. 

Can I use this live query in my Vue project or is this react only?

Comment: liveQuery is framework agnostic. Here's an example (made with my limited knowledge about vue): https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-tereshkova-b6dfi?file=/src/components/DBItems.vue